# What does "peanuts" mean in "all them peanuts"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Today I came across [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323810/350567) somewhere on Stack Exchange (you need 10k to see). It was blatantly off-topic and a moderator closed it. The user responded in comments:

> nope..... im here for the communty and all them **peanuts**!!

I headed over to chat and [asked](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7549395) people if they knew, and someone responded with "Iceland Friday". [It didn't make any sense](https://www.google.com/search?q=iceland+friday+peanuts) to me however. I also looked up [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peanut) and all 4 entries didn't make sense, either.

What is the meaning of "peanuts" in [the context](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peanut)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a reference to "[peanut gallery](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/peanut-gallery)" which is a term used to describe rowdy audiences or hecklers, or more generally to people who are criticizing in a less than helpful way.

A few examples where it might be used:

- Someone is driving, and their passengers are complaining about how they are driving or what route they are taking. The driver says, "Quiet from the peanut gallery, please!"
- A teacher is trying to find a piece of chalk to write on the board. A student says, "Have you tried turning it off and turning it on again?" The teacher says, "No commentary from the peanut gallery."

In the case of your example, someone saying they are on stack exchange "for the peanuts" may mean that they don't believe the answers are particularly valuable.